# Jquery validation for dynamically created form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am creating a form dynamically when a user clicks the reply button. Now I want to validate the form that is created before submission.

I have seen similar questions for dynamically created form elements, but what about a form? I can't seem to make this work? Must be something simple I'm missing? Do I need to bind the form validation another way?

The HTML sample below is loaded by ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#postroll").on("click", ".reply", function() {
  var row=$(this).parent().parent();
  var postid=$(this).attr("postid");
  $("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><form name='reply' id='reply' method='post' action='ajax.php'><div class='form-group'><textarea class='form-control' name='replymessage' id='replymessage' rows='3'  data-rule-required='true'></textarea><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Submit</button></div></form></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>").insertAfter(row);
 });
 
 $("#reply").validate({
  onkeyup: false,
  onclick: false,
  highlight: function(element) {
   $(element).parent().addClass("has-error");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
   $(element).parent().removeClass("has-error");
  },   
  errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
   return true;
  },    
  submitHandler: function() {
   var postData = $("#reply").serializeArray();
   var formURL = $("#reply").attr("action");
   $.ajax({
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success : function() {
     $("#success").show();
     $("#success").fadeOut(3000);
    },
    error : function() {
     $("#fail").show();
     $("#fail").fadeOut(3000);
    }
   });
  }  
 }); 
});
```

```html
<div id="postroll">
  <input id="currentpage" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input id="pagecount" type="hidden" value="27">
  <input id="currentsort" type="hidden" value="0">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:20%">User</th>
        <th style="width:60%">Message</th>
        <th style="width:20%"> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Message here.</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary confirm">Delete</button>
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default cancel" style="display:none">
          <button id="280" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" style="display:none">Confirm</button>
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary reply" postid="280" style="display: inline-block;">Reply</button>
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger cancel_reply" style="display: none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include the html

Comment: Thanks. HTML for #postroll is added via ajax ... will pull a sample.

Comment: Your form isn't being created until the postroll button is clicked. So when `$("#reply").validate` is evaluated `reply` doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How would I evaluate this after? Within the click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by LAROmega - the validate function was being evaluated before the form was created. I moved validate into the click function after the form creation.

```js
 $("#postroll").on("click", ".reply", function() {
  var row=$(this).parent().parent();
  var postid=$(this).attr("postid");
  $(this).next(".cancel_reply").show();
  $("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><form name='reply' id='reply' method='post' action='ajax.php'><div class='form-group'><textarea class='form-control' name='replymessage' id='replymessage' rows='3'  data-rule-required='true'></textarea><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Submit</button></div></form></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>").insertAfter(row);
  $("#reply").validate({
   onkeyup: false,
   onclick: false,
   highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass("has-error");
   },
   unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass("has-error");
   },   
   errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
   },    
   submitHandler: function() {
    var postData = $("#reply").serializeArray();
    var formURL = $("#reply").attr("action");
    $.ajax({
     url : formURL,
     type: "POST",
     data : postData,
     success : function() {
      $("#success").show();
      $("#success").fadeOut(3000);
     },
     error : function() {
      $("#fail").show();
      $("#fail").fadeOut(3000);
     }
    });
   }  
  });   
 });
```